# Can i replace One big transformer with two

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, lcd, electricity

My LCD screen is noisy and the source of that noise is that big transformer inside the red circle, i want to change it but i cant find it anywhere,
so im thinking if i can replace it with two little transformers from an old lcd screen (green circle) ??[image: transformers]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by noisy? what effect do you see on your screen in that regard? What makes you so sure that the culprit is the transformer?

Comment: i opened the casing and listened to it , the picture is fine but its too annoying it cause me headache this is the sound (ssssssssssssssssss) :D by the way i tried changing the caps but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: That sound may come from the mechanical stress caused by the high frequency magnetic field. Though changing the transformer may make it vanish, it might also make it much worse. And as Tony said in his answer, the transformers parameters need to match since the ratio of windings determine the output voltage. If it differs the backlight could be too low or high, or you might even damage the tubes or start a fire. So if your question is "can I?" (I can't find a clear question, actually), I'd say: "no you can't". Note that the sound could also come from other parts. "ssss..." is too unprecise.

Answer (score 4):

The noisy video on the LCD is most likely due to arcing in the CCFL high voltage board but the actual root cause is unclear.

If you are certain the transformer is flawed , a replacement will need exact parametric properties to meet the requirements of the CCFL driver IC.

This would include inductance, turns ratio, HiV rating value, self resonant frequency because this operates with PWM using zero-valley switching to regulate the trigger voltage and sustaining current thru each CCFL within the range of operating frequencies used. There are finely tuned RC delays on board to match these characteristics.

It may be easier to replace the board.

Phosphor wear and contamination to the CCFL's increase conduction current along with declining brightness and it may be time to replace the tubes as well from Digikey according to length and thickness [mm].

Here are the [IC specs.](http://dalincom.ru/datasheet/BIT3105.pdf)

Comment: man i want to replace that big transformer with those two circled in green not the opposite that board is actually the OLD one im gonna take those two transformers from it

Comment: when I said "It may be easier to replace the board. "  It means the board where the so-called defective part came from. The assumption that you could get any backlight at all, meant it was operating.

Comment: IC specs say 30 to 200kHz, maybe you can try crazy glue on the perhaps loose windings, but more likely it is piezo effects of magnetostiction of ferrite

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't replace one transformer that has one core by two separate transformers. That's kind of obvious – the one contiguous core is what transports energy between the sides of the transformer, and you'd be severing that tie. This also illustrates the point try-catch-finally made in the comments under your question:

It might be possible to replace a transformer with one of matching specs, but you, as it seems, are not experienced enough to find one.

Aside from that:

Screens are relatively cheap these days – you might want to look into simply getting a new one; it's often an investment that pays for itself relatively quickly due to reduced power usage and increased productivity. If your current screen gives you headaches by making much noise, chances are there's more wrong with it than just a transformer.